# Problem on understanding the definition of "Real Numbers"

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Assume that a cut is defined like this :

A cut of a set like $M$ is a subset of $M$ like $A$ such that :
1. $A \neq \emptyset $ and $A\neq M$
2. $\forall a,b \in M \space \space a\in A \space\land b<a \implies b \in A$
3. $A$ doesn't have a maximum.

Then, we can define real numbers like this :
$R=\{A\subseteq \Bbb Q :A \text{ is  a  cut}\}$

Now, I have three problems.

1. Isn't $\Bbb R$ supposed to be larger than $\Bbb Q$? I've learned that $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb R$ . But with this definition, $\Bbb R$ is the union of many subsets of $\Bbb Q$. So again, it's a subset of $\Bbb Q$ .
2. What's the reason of adding the 3rd statement?
3. From second statement, Can we conclude that $A$ doesn't have minimum?

Note 1 : By $\Bbb Q$, I mean Rational Numbers.

Note 2 : This is the definition of one my professors who wanted to explain it briefly. I'm not sure if it's complete or wrong.  That's why I asked it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course $\mathbb{R}$ has larger cardinality than $\mathbb{Q}$ but I believe their definition refers to the union of all such cuts.

Comment: Hang on, if you're defining $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of sets of elements from $\mathbb{Q}$ then, surely, it'll only have rational numbers in it?

Comment: @Jam That's one of the reasons i'm confused :)

Comment: It's not the *union* of such cuts, its the *collection* of such cuts.  Cuts are not *subsets* of $\Bbb R$, they are the *elements* of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So, for example, how is the square root of $2$ defined in this context?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't really understand; if $\mathbb{R}$ is a collection of cuts and cuts are sets then wouldn't that make $\mathbb{R}$ a set of sets, not a set of numbers?

Comment: The idea is that we can treat these sets like numbers.  For example, we could define $\sqrt{2}$ to be the cut
$$
\sqrt{2} = \{x \in \Bbb Q: x^2 < 2 \text{ or } x < 0\}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah, Hagen von Eitzens answer cleared up my question but thanks though :)

Comment: The important bit about the second statement is that not only does a cut have no minimum, it also has *no lower bound*.  In general, cuts will not have a maximum, but may have an upper bound.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and Jam Great discussion ! Thank you both

Comment: **Note:** These cuts are sometimes called [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $\mathbb{R}$ is not the union of many subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, it qualifies as a so called limit union of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, the set of all rational numbers such that $x^2 < 2$ has no equivalent rational representation. This is the union of all sets of the form $x^2 < q$ where $q < 2$, which are all represented by rational numbers, but then the cut itself is not a rational number.

2) I don't know, to be fair, but the answer somewhat stems from the fact that if both open and closed intervals were allowed, then each real number would have identity crisis, because we would not know whether to associate it to  the open or closed interval.

3) Yes, we can conclude that $A$ does not have a minimum whenever $M$ doesn't have a minimum, because then for every $a$ in $A$ we have some $b \in M$ smaller than $a$, then $b \in A$, so $A$ has no minimum. However, if $M$ has a minimal element, then $A$ can consist solely of that minimal element, for example.

Comment: Thank you, @ArmanMalekzade. Please don't call me sir, I may be younger than you.

Answer (score 2):

1. The elements of $\Bbb R$, defined like this, are (infinite) **subsets** of $\Bbb Q$. Hence no element of $\Bbb R$ is an **element** of $\Bbb Q$. For now, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ are disjoint. However, we can *identify* $\Bbb Q$ with a subset of $\Bbb R$ in a natural way, by identifying the rational number $q$ with the cut $\{\,x\in \Bbb Q\mid x<q\,\}$.
2. If we allow maxima, the sets $\{\,x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\le 0\,\}$ and $\{\,x\in\Bbb Q\mid x< 0\,\}$ would both be cuts. This is not what we want (it just doesn't work out when proceding).
3. No, see above.

Comment: Thank you :) Helped me a lot ... but about the 3rd question ... Are you sure ?

Comment: I don't understand your answer to 3.  Certainly, the 3rd part of the definition allows us to conclude that a cut should not have a minimum (or, for that matter, a lower bound)

Comment: no element of $R$ is an element of $Q$  ? you mean, for example,  "2" in $R$ is different from "2" in $Q$?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade indeed, $2$ as an element of $\Bbb R$, by this definition of $\Bbb R$, might be given as 
$$
2 = \{x \in \Bbb Q : x < 2\} \in \Bbb R
$$